# How can I fix that line re.sub

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pass a variable to `re.sub` but there is an error and I can't figure out how to fix it?

```
preset_name = "preset "
data = re.sub("name=\"%s[^]]*/select", lambda x:x.group(0).replace('selected',''), html) % preset_name
```

Here is the error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: What's wrong with `"name=" + preset_name + "[^]]*.."`?

Comment: `%` should be following the string directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data =re.sub("name=\"%s[^]]*/select" % preset_name, lambda x:x.group(0).replace('selected',''), html)
```

`%` operates on string